# perl to open csv file with dynamic date in it?

Tags: perl

How can I open a CSV file with a date that changes each day, where the date format is `yyyy` for year, `dd` for day and `mmm` for a 3 letter month.

This is as far as I've got

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  #Set-up Input Files
  #Inputfile
  $INFILE = "C:\\DBR_%yyyy\\%b\\Failures_input%d%h\\.csv";

  #Open input file for reading
  open (INPUT,"$INFILE") or die " cannot open $INFILE  ";
```

Comment: ... And `%d` is presumably the day of the month, and `%h` the hour of the day?

Comment: Why does your file end with `\\.csv`? Do you *really* have files called `.csv` contained in directories named by the day and hour?

Comment: When you say *"open"*, do you mean "find and open for reading" or do you mean "create"? If you are intending to create files with a path like this then please *don't*, precisely because the opposite problem - finding the latest file - is so damn messy if you use this design. Also, please *never* use anything but numeric months, because it is a pain to sort, and because the name varies with the locale.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, in answer to your questions. I am trying to open the file. the %d is for the day ie "01","02" etc the %h is wrong it should be for abbrevated month ie "jan", "feb" ,"mar".yes the files i am trying to open are.csv.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unclear what you are asking for, and you don't mention `%d` and `%h` in your pattern.

If you want to *open* the latest CSV file then you need to do a nested search of the path, finding the latest date and time.

Here is something that may help. This code generates the path to the file that would be created for the current date and time. It uses the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module, which is part of core Perl and shouldn't need installing. By default it overloads the `localtime` operator so that it returns a `Time::Piece` object in scalar context. That allows the module's utility methods to be applied directly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $failures_file = localtime->strftime('C:\DBR_%Y\%b\Failures_input%d%b.csv');
my $invoices_file = localtime->strftime('C:\%Y\%b\invoices%d%b.csv');

print $failures_file, "\n";
print $invoices_file, "\n";
```

**output**

```
C:\DBR_2014\Mar\Failures_input17Mar.csv
C:\2014\Mar\invoices17Mar.csv
```

However I think it is more likely that you want the name of the *latest* file with a path of that form, which is a little more complex (and a dreadful system design). Please verify your requirement and we will be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i wish to open a csv file for reading, the files is saved each day by the user as 'C:\2014\Mar\invoices17Mar.csv' for example.

Comment: Okay I have modified my answer to show the format of the file path that you now say you want. I have included exmaples for both the failures file that you mantion in your question, and the invoices file that you put in your comment.

Comment: thanks again for your help, when i try this i get the message         Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib
.) at C:\scripts\test2.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\scripts\test2.pl line 4.

Comment: Then you don't have `Time::Piece` installed. What version of Perl are you using? That module has been part of core Perl for nearly seven years now. You probably need to upgrade Perl.

Comment: hi, i have perl 5.8 build 820. but i get 401 authorisation error, i there any way to instal the package without the busisness edition ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by *"business edition"*. You should start a new question, and explain exactly what you are doing to get the 401 error, together with any other output.

Comment: Hi when i try to instal the module this happens                       Time-Piece marked for install
Installing package ... 
  Downloading Time-Piece-1.15 ... redirect
  Downloading Time-Piece-1.15 ... failed 401 Authorization Required
Installing package failed  401 Authorization Required

Comment: Sure. As I said, you should start a new question. No one will see it here buried in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write an answer about the `localtime` Perl function, but [its documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) is so complete that it even includes stuff about the three-letter abbreviations.

A few remarks on your string literal for the filename:

- You can use single forward slashes, even on Windows
- You don't have to escape the dot with a backslash
- You can "interpolate" variables into strings: `"DBR_$yyyy"` if `$yyyy` is a variable.

Comment: I should add that the path is hard coded to windows and machine / product specific.  Good coding would involve a config file and adapting to both unix and windows world. I would move the data files into a \datadir\ not off the root directory of the windows machine.

Comment: @alexmac: While well-meaning, your comment isn't helpful. It is far from ideal to build portability into everything.

Comment: It's experience dealing with code that creeps across OS boundaries,  from many years of experience at places like Morgan Stanley, Citi, TD, etc. :)

Comment: @alexmac: It may be useful to allow configuration for *likely* platforms, but I'm damned if I'm going to support CP/M in my Windows Perl code.

Comment: @Borodin, agreed... I was thinking more a windows / linux ... :) I understand your point though.

Comment: Loved it, hours though were harsh.

Answer (score 0):

I second SzG's general recommendations.

The following shows how to add the date formatting to your filename using two core modules.

Using [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) (in Perl core since version 5.8):

```
use Time::Piece;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = localtime->strftime('C:\DBR_%Y\%b\Failures_input%d.csv');
```

Or using [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) and strftime if you're working on an ancient box.  To find the available specifiers, just [google strftime](https://www.google.com/search?q=strftime):

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = strftime 'C:\DBR_%Y\%b\Failures_input%d.csv', localtime;
```

Outputs:

```
C:\DBR_2014\Mar\Failures_input16.csv
```

Comment: I recommend avoiding the `POSIX` module. It is *enormous*, so it will have a huge impact on load time, and is rarely useful except for one or two functions.

Comment: Aye, I'd only use it on very old boxes.  Still have memories of working with Perl 5.6.  However, I switched the order of my module recommendation so that I mention the preferred `Time::Piece` first.

Comment: Sites running anything earlier than version 10 should be left to deal with the consequences.